# Problem about Gaussian prime

Tags: gaussian-integers

I asked a question before. I am asking the same question again but in different manner with less confusion.

How can we prove that a Gaussian integer is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ only when the norm of $z$, $N(z)$ is a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$? Is there any Gaussian integer $z$ ( not on real or imaginary axes) whose norm is composite in $\mathbb{Z}$ but $z$ is itself a  prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: Note that the norm is completely multiplicative (since it's just a product running over a set of monomorphisms).

Comment: An element of $\mathbb Z[i]$ is prime iff its norm is prime *or* it is $\pm p$ or $\pm ip$ for some prime $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

Comment: Link to the earlier question you mention: [Gaussian Integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201377/gaussian-integer)

Comment: I found the answer. If Z is prime, Z'( conjugate of Z), if the norm of Z ,N(Z) is composite , and if N(d)|N(Z) ,     ( N(d)<N(z) ) ,then z or z' would not be a prime at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by Wojowu already supplies the full answer.

So you get a counterexample by considering Gaussian integers like $\pm 3$ and $\pm 3i$. They are Gaussian primes, but their norms, $N(\pm 3) = N(\pm 3i) = 9$ are composite (9 is a composite number).

As is also contained in Wojowu's comment, the *only* counterexamples are Gaussian primes of the type $\pm p$ and $\pm ip$ where $p$ is a positive prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ (i.e. $p$ leaves a remainder of $3$ when divided by $4$). Their norms $p^2$ are composite.

Comment: I am saying, can we find a Gaussian integer (not on the real or imaginary axis) whose norm is a ordinary complex number but the Gaussian integer is itself a prime in Z[i]

Comment: If you take _any_ prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ that _is not_ on the real or imaginary axis, then its norm $N$ (which is the square of the "diagonal" distance from zero) will be a (rational) prime. Its norm cannot be anything else. I do not know why you write "norm is a ordinary complex number".

Answer (score 0):

There is a notion of prime in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as a prime is defined to an irreducible element in an integral domain, and $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an integral domain, and the elements in the gaussian integers which have a prime norm are not always irreducible, if they are of form $4k+1$, then they are reducible(i mentioned in the answer of your previous question). But if the norm is not of form $4k+1$ and it is also a prime norm, then it is of couse irreducible, and hence can be called as a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: But if the norm of a Gaussian integer is a prime p. Then p is always 1 modulo 4. We can't find such a prime norm ( except real or imaginary axes) which is 3 modulo 4.